# Can thoughts materialize?

Tags: belief

Many people believe that their good or bad thoughts can materialize in the future. So some people try to be always in good mood and think positively. Others are not so happy and just try not to think about bad things too often to prevent them from happening. And finally there are large groups of people that pray to some god. Can thoughts of all these people materialize into a real events, creatures, things? At least sometimes?

Comment: In Mahayana, vows are considered to be more powerful and efficacious that mundane statements.  Also, mindfulness, in that context, such as being mindful of a Buddha or Pure land, leads to effects, at least after life. Mantrayana, is essentially, statements for this worldly benefit.

Comment: Perhaps a better title might be "does positive thinking create a positive future?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Many people believe that their good or bad thoughts can materialize in the future.**

**Yes**.In the Dhammapada it says *The Mind is the forerunner of all things*. Everything begins in the mind.From the most subtlest intentions to thoughts.

**So some people try to be always in good mood and think positively**.

When you think good thoughts,you tend to feel good,you tend to do good,and you create good,and enjoy the fruits of your goodness.But this does not happen linearly.So you may think positive but still struggle with depression due to the bad thoughts you have ruminated about in the past.Only because you don't see the results right away doesn't mean nothing's happening.

Also it's very important to define good thoughts.Good thoughts refers to thoughts that are skillful or wholesome.Not just thoughts that feels good.As it is possible to have positive thinking and be delusional at the same time.And it is possible to think of unwholesome things that feel good but brings suffering.

**Others are not so happy and just try not to think about bad things too often to prevent them from happening**.

To think that by "not thinking about it" they can prevent bad things from happening is slightly delusional.Depends on one's karma.If the fruit of a bad karma ripens due to to the right conditions then ... no amount of "not thinking about it" will stop it.*Neither in the sky nor in mid-ocean, nor by entering into mountain clefts, nowhere in the world is there a place where one may escape from the results of evil deeds.*-*Dhammapada*

**And finally there are large groups of people that pray to some god.**

It all depends on the individual themselves.Whether they pray to a God or not the key that makes these thoughts materialize is their intentions,their karma,their actions.

**Can thoughts of all these people materialize into a real events, creatures, things? At least sometimes?**

Yes thoughts can materialize because of cause and effect.But they are governed by certain laws.Law of gravity,law of karma,law of nature etc and also our own actions and in actions.We can wish for a good meal,but if we don't get up and make it and no one comes by and makes it for us then we're not going to have one.

Answer (score 5):

> Many people believe that their good or bad thoughts can materialize in
>   the future

Yes, this is called Kamma. Good thoughts have the potential to cause good consequences. Bad thoughts have the potential to cause bad consequences.
But the Buddhist way of identifying a good/bad thoughts has nothing to do with positive/negative thinking.
If a thought is tainted with craving, aversion and ignorance, it is a bad thought. If not, it is a good thought.

ex: Going after a mirage, thinking that it's a real stream of water can be a positive thought, if you really believe in it. But it's not going to bring intended results. Thinking that slaughtering animals and offering them to a god/demon will result in a good harvest can be a positive thought. But it is a bad thought according to Buddhism. Thinking that there's an all loving, all governing god who's going to save you from suffering can be a positive thought. But it is a bad thought according to Buddhism. Thinking about impermanence, suffering can be taken as negative thinking. But they are good thoughts according to Buddhism.

All bad thoughts have the potential to give repercussions. But not all good thoughts give future results. Ex: the thoughts of enlightened being are called [Kiriya citta](http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/g_m/kiriya.htm). You could call them neutral, but they are good since they don't cause harm.

> So some people try to be always in good mood and think positively.
>   Others are not so happy and just try not to think about bad things too
>   often to prevent them from happening.

This is not possible! Bad and good things happen because of causes. If the causes are not present for something to happen, you simply can't make it happen, regardless of your mood.
To take the same example, just because you pray to a god, you won't get the things you pray for. There should be someone listening, who is in a position to give you what you want. And that being should decide to help in the way you want.

Comment: Excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think yes: "at least sometimes".

Imagine if you're a salesperson, trying to sell something -- it will help to be cheerful and confident, i.e. people are more likely to want to buy from you ... and you're more likely to be willing to try (and try again after each failure).

But the "thoughts" are not enough -- e.g. I suppose that whether you're a successful salesperson would also depend on what you're selling, what the customer needs, whether they afford it, etc.

There's a sutta that might be relevant, [SN 42.6](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn42/sn42.006.than.html) -- you can't make a boulder float on a lake just by praying.

Although "state of mind" is relevant generally, see e.g. [Mental factors (Buddhism)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mental_factors_(Buddhism)).

But what you're describing might be [magical thinking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_thinking), which maybe isn't Buddhist.

But I think that part of the training of modern professional/trained athletes is to imagine themselves winning -- e.g. to imagine and re-imagine in detail, to foresee, to plan, what it feels like and the various details of what a body does, to run 100 meters in 9.8 seconds. That imagination is a kind of planning for the future. That's not exactly "magical" though (e.g. they'd do it as well as, not instead of, physical training) -- and some Buddhist practices (e.g. *bhavana* meditation, maybe *tantrayana* too) might be like that, analogous to that.

Answer (score 0):

...According to the Buddha, the best we can do is looking objectively at *Dhamma*, our essential nature: knowing and seeing the sensorial world as it really is. *Yathabhuta nana dassana*.

Then awareness and equanimity will lead automatically to liberation of the self.

Shaila Catherine—*Focused and Fearless. A Meditator’s Guide to States of Deep Joy, Calm, and Clarity (2008)  p. 149*:

> *‘When the mind is profoundly balanced with equanimity, there is no averse reaction to the basic fact that nothing in the material world can bring satisfaction.’*

Then we 'know' and 'see' that *'nothing in the material world can bring satisfaction':*

Samyutta Nikaya (1.168):

> *'The entire world is in flames,
>   the entire world is going up in smoke;
>   the entire world is burning,
>   the entire world is vibrating.
>   But that which does not vibrate or burn,
>   which is experienced by the noble ones,
>   where death has no entry—
>   in that my mind delights.'*

Answer (score 0):

Thoughts can in fact materialize. It seems that it violates the laws of nature but it doesn't. We are only beginning to learn about how our universe works. The following website explains it in more detail:

https://sites.google.com/site/materializationbythought/home?previewAsViewer=1

Comment: Hello and welcome to Buddhism SE. When adding links or references to an answer, please add a description of the the link in case the link should cease to exist.

Answer (score 0):

When religion or dogma,or politics presses you ,especially in religion  where info and symbolism is illusiimal or delusional ,this religious information of existence  of evil or good deities wars and persecution,witchcraft, against you enter you,become permanent thought and will be materialized.  That's why so much calamities and madness happened to people and mankind .. I was also one of that victim . People become engaged in illusions internal and external  wars.. Where people wanted to find smooth medicine they found antagonistic opposition between unseen powers,and that makes people captivated